# Multiple iterators (using enumerate) for the same iterable, what is going on?

Tags: python, iterator

Consider the following example:

```
s = 'abc'
[(c1, c2) for j, c2 in enumerate(s) for i, c1 in enumerate(s)]
```

Output:

```
[('a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('c', 'c')]
```

I would expected the same output if enumerate is called outside the list comprehension and the iterators are assigned to variables:

```
it1, it2 = enumerate(s), enumerate(s)
[(c1, c2) for j, c2 in it1 for i, c1 in it2]
```

But I get:

```
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'a')]
```

What is going on? I use Python 3.6.9.

Comment: In the first way after every iteration a new iterator is created while in the second it is created only once. That's what I think it's happening.

Comment: As @dcg said after the first iteration it2 is empty

Comment: Ah right how could I miss that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is happening is that the *inner* iterator gets exhausted after the first iteration of the *outer* iterator:

```
s = 'abc'
it1 = enumerate(s)
it2 = enumerate(s)

for i, x in it1:
    for j, y in it2:  # <-- gets consumed when i = 0 and stays empty
        ...
```

By contrast:

```
s = 'abc'

for i, x in enumerate(s):
    for j, y in enumerate(s):  # <-- gets recreated at each iteration
        ....
```

---

If you need *persistence*, enclose it in a `list` or `tuple`:

```
itr = list(enumerate(s))
print([(c1, c2) for j, c2 in itr for i, c1 in itr])
# [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'c')]
```

although note the different memory footprint of using `enumerate()` multiple times versus having it enclosed in a `list` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that in:

```
s = 'abc'
[(c1, c2) for j, c2 in enumerate(s) for i, c1 in enumerate(s)]
```

A **new** `c1` enumerator is created for each value yielded on the first `for`. While on your second example, the same enumerator is used (it2) - and it gets exausted once it reaches "c" - when the first `for` advances to the next iteration (c2 = "b") and tries to iterate "it2", it is already exhausted - and the whole expression ends.

Answer (score 1):

[enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) build-in function returns an `iterator`, once the elements are exhausted it stops

in your first version, you are building a new `enumerate(s)` for each iteration of the first loop and in the second loop you are consuming it,

in your second version, `it2` has finished his elements from the first iteration of the first loop

```
s = 'abc'

def my_enumerate(s, name):
    print('a new enumerate: ', name)
    for i in enumerate(s):
        yield i
    print(f'the enumerate {name} is exhausted ')

[(c1, c2) for j, c2 in my_enumerate(s, 'it1') for i, c1 in my_enumerate(s, 'it2')]
```

output:

```
a new enumerate:  it1
a new enumerate:  it2
the enumerate it2 is exhausted 
a new enumerate:  it2
the enumerate it2 is exhausted 
a new enumerate:  it2
the enumerate it2 is exhausted 
the enumerate it1 is exhausted 
[('a', 'a'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('b', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c'),
 ('c', 'c')]
```

and for:

```
it1, it2 = my_enumerate(s, 'it1'), my_enumerate(s, 'it2')
[(c1, c2) for j, c2 in it1 for i, c1 in it2]
```

output:

```
a new enumerate:  it1
a new enumerate:  it2
the enumerate it2 is exhausted 
the enumerate it1 is exhausted 
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'a'), ('c', 'a')]
```